# finding vector parallel to a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-verification, analytic-geometry

$g: \begin{cases}
x=3s \\
y=0 \\
z=1-4s
\end{cases}$

How do I find the coordinates of a vector $e_2$ which is parallel to g, and $|e_2|=1?$

I know that $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}=1$.

I assume that the line is passing through a point (0,0,1) and it has direction the vector (3,0,-4).

So is it alright just to use the second coordinates (the ones in front of the scalar s) and make sure the norm is 1?

$e_2(\frac{3}{5}, 0, -\frac{4}{5})$

Is this an ok solution?

Comment: Correct, fine, perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: the straight line is given by $$[x,y,z]=[0,0,1]+s[3,0,-4]$$ thus our serached vector is $$[3m,0,-4m]$$ with $\sqrt{9m^2+16m^2}=1$ from here you will get $m$

Comment: Thanks! Having it written is a lot cleaner. I was just doing it in my head which doesn't work with more complicated examples.

Comment: ok that is good